# What's the difference between keywords 'test' and 'it'

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tdd, integration-testing

In a few different testing frameworks I've seen some people using keyword 'test' and some using 'it' when creating tests, while both seem to be valid keywords and don't seem to change the test at all.

So what are the differences and where should I use them?

Tried googling this but you can imagine how Google might not understand 'test' and 'it' as coding keywords so the results had no info on this issue.

**EDIT**

The framework I'm getting familiar with is Jest for JS-testing. Their docs give no direction as to which one to use. I've also checked other JS-testing frameworks which haven't given consistent answers.

Answer (score 0):

For example of two PHP frameworks:

- PHPUnit
- PHPSpec

They both have other purpouse and then you should use them in other way and context.

#### PHPUnit

Main framework to use with unit testing. In here you use `test` and start describing what is tested. In here, you focus on tested functionality. Like: `testGetAnswerReturnCorrectResult` - you have given functionality and now you testing this.

#### PHPSpec

Main framework for TDD creating project. In here you use `it` at start of testing function. In total, full name like : `it_should_return_instance_by_get_answer` describe some story of expected result. In TDD you first write down test, then code.

If you consider the context, then authors of given framework are right to use others keyword to describe this process.

It is about how next programmer will receive your code and tests that you let him - it is more about readability, than technical functionality.

Comment: strange that these PHP-frameworks connect 'test' with unit testing and 'it' with TDD, because after fast scrolling through Mocha's (JS-testing) docs it feels like they do it exactly other way.
Right now I'm getting familiar with Jest which gives no direction about this in it's docs.

Comment: It all depends on intension of authors of framework, but, in my opinion, the way that work for the one, I described, is very intuitive.

Other languages have own standards, policy - that way it is not surprising to have such difference.